# Using do_shortcode() with contact form 7 and form tag is missing

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I’m trying to use the contact form in my template using do_shortcode and popup (Request availability button on a page). But I’ve noticed that form generated only inputs without `<form>` tag as usual so it failed to submit.

That’s how I’m implementing it in functions.php

```
function wc_shop_popup() {
    $reqform = '[contact-form-7 id="987" title="Request availability"]';
    echo '<a class="button button_full_width button_left req_button popup-link" href="#popup-availability" rel="lightbox" data-type="inline"><span class="button_icon"><i class="icon-layout"></i></span><span class="button_label">Request Availability</span></a>
    <div id="popup-availability" class="popup-content mfp-hide"><div class="popup-inner" style="padding:20px;">'.do_shortcode($reqform).'</div></div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_popup' );
```

This is the [page](https://wholesalehandsanitizer.ca/product/bioam-30ml-1oz-travel-hand-sanitizer-wholesale/) - Request availability button. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be form submission fails due to something else like could it be JavaScript errors in console as it is popup so maybe some other broken js on the page breaking cf7 js submit operation?

Comment: there are no errors in the console. the problem is there is no form tag with method and action generated that's why submit button doesn't work

Comment: Does your form work if you build a test page, and put the cf-7 shortcode?

Comment: Yes, it does. I guess I have found the problem. I'm using do_shortcode inside of the add to cart form. So it seems like it generates inside and failed to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that contact form has been generated inside of add to cart form. I used another woocommerce hook called "woocommerce_after_single_product_summary" instead of "woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button" and it's working!